# For some reason can't hear the music in Godot engine

Tags: c#, godot

Here's the C# code for the music part. For some reason I cannot hear the music. The path to the file is correct.

```
public override void _Ready()
{
    var streamPlayer = GetNode<AudioStreamPlayer2D>("AudioStreamPlayer2D");
    streamPlayer.Stream = GD.Load<AudioStream>("res://music.mp3");
    streamPlayer.Play();
}
```

There's no error, just no music sounds.
Here are the errors:[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46RGp.png)

Comment: "There's no error ... Here are the errors" - if there *are* errors, why have you said there are no errors? I don't understand...

Comment: (Have you debugged through the code? Is `streamPlayer` definitely not null?)

Comment: Should I debug using an IDE?  @JonSkeet I'm sorry I'm kind of new to all this.

Comment: Yes. If you're very new to programming in C# in general, I would personally suggest starting *not* in Godot engine - learn the basics writing simple console apps before you move on to more advanced environments.

Comment: How does the scene tree looks like? I'm guessing there isn't a `AudioStreamPlayer2D` with the name `"AudioStreamPlayer2D"` child of the Node with this script.

Comment: I strongly recommend posting error messages as formatted text instead of images. Some of the [many reasons to post errors/code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/950488) include making your question more searchable, and more accessible for folks using screen readers or translation software, making it easier for folks to help you. Screenshots are fine for things like Godot's Scene / Node tree & Inspector. Error/code screenshots also tends to attract downvotes.